# Javascript: How to show tooltip by hovering mouse over axis lable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I am using parallel coordinates to visualize some data.
I used most of the codes from the website below:

https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/examples/table.html

Now, I want to add tooltip to the labels of the vertical lines. When a user hover mouse over a label the description of that label will appear in a box.

I want to add the description of each label manually by if else function, because I dont have the desciptions in a stored in a database. In a way that if someone hover over "cylinders" (it is the label of one axis) the description related to that appear in a box.

I used "mouseover" in the code below, but it is not working:

```
g.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
  .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(yscale[d])); })
.append("svg:text")
  .attr({
    "text-anchor": "middle",
    "y": -10,
    "transform": "translate(0,-5) rotate(" + __.dimensionTitleRotation + ")",
    "x": 0,
    "class": "label"
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d in __.dimensionTitles ? __.dimensionTitles[d] : d;  // dimension display names
  })
  .on("dblclick", flipAxisAndUpdatePCP)
  .on("mouseover", function(d){
             if d == "economy" {
                 return popover("some descition about economy");
             }else ifd == ""cylinder" {
                 return popover("some descition about cylinder");
             });
```

I know it has some problems but dont know how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your question is not clear, make it point wise where do you want to see what ? And from where do you get the data for tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to add an html div for the tooltip and modify based on the location of the mouse.  You can refer to the below block for more information:
http://bl.ocks.org/wdickerson/64535aff478e8a9fd9d9facccfef8929